# Deserialize JSON object into a class with a "dynamic" property

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am receiving JSON messages that are matched to the following class:

```
public class Response
{
    public int Code { get; }
    public string Message { get; }
    public string Result { get; }
}
```

But the value of `Result` property depends on what we get in `Code` and does not have a fixed structure.

E.g. if `Code = 1`, Result will return a list of objects of type X and if `Code = 2`, Result will return a list of objects of type Y.

When I try to deserialize a message I am receiving, having Result type set to `string` does not seem to work.

```
var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
if (responseObj.Code == 1)
{
    return responseObj.Result;
}
```

The return statement above throws the following exception:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'Result'

How can I define my class so that it receives the entire text of Result and I can decide about its deserialization later? Because all my requests respond to with the above structure and I'd like to manage all these requests from the same place.

Comment: The `Result` property is `List<object>`, not a string

Comment: Sounds like maybe your data is an array, not an object or string. You can't deserialise an array into a string. You need some sort of list. Can you show us the JSON?

Comment: @Fabjan true. But how can I get a string representation of that object?

Comment: why would you want a string representation of it??

Comment: @ADyson because I want to deserialize it later. I, first get the base Response and then decide whether I should deserialize the Result property into an object of type X or Y. So I'd like to send Result back to the program as a string. Better suggestions are, of course, appreciated.

Comment: you could be perhaps use `dynamic` or `List<dynamic>`. You can't expect to only deserialise part of the JSON - it's treated as one coherent unit. Better still would be to tell your code what type to deserialise to. Is there any way for you to know, based on the request you made to the API, what kind of list you're going to get back? Really an API response should be deterministic - you should know exactly what format of data you're going to get out based on what you put in. If it varies according to some internal logic then that's a bad design IMHO, precisely because it causes issues like this.

Comment: @ADyson Unfortunately, the JSON deserializer cannot interpret either `List<dynamic>` or `dynamic`. And yes, my old solution used different objects based on different response JSON. But the thought behind my new approach was to have one initial method to just check whether the request is receiving a correct response and then send the rest of deserialization to another method.

Comment: That just doesn't work conceptually, you can't partially de-serialise an object. You either de-serialise it, or you don't. If you want to do something like have one method which handles all HTTP calls, then you could use generics so that the caller could pass in the type it wants the response to be deserialised to.

Comment: P.S. I have de-serialised things to `dynamic` and also `List<dynamic>` successfully before now, so it's unclear why that's an issue here. Do you get a specific error? I was meaning that you would change `public string Result { get; }` to `public List<dynamic> Result { get; }`. Not sure if having read-only properties is a problem by the way, dunno if the deserialiser needs them to be writable in order to populate the object.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I define my class so that it receives the entire text of Result and I can decide about its deserialization later?*

If that is what you want to do then make your `Result` property a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) instead of a `string` as shown below.  You will also need to add setters to all of the properties shown in your `Response` class to allow the deserialization to work properly: you can't deserialize into read-only properties.

```
public class Response
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public JToken Result { get; set; }
}
```

Once you know what type the `Result` should be converted into, you can use the [`ToObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) method to do that.  For example:

```
Response responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);

if (responseObj.Code == 1)
{
    var listOfX = responseObj.Result.ToObject<List<X>>();
    ...
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pz5m63